# SQL Tedious Loop through object of array and execute insert statement function error Request is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, for-loop, tedious, tediousjs

I'm new to Js, and would appreciate some help.

Currently, via tedious js, I've written a sql function that passes an insert statement that loops through an array of objects and inserts each property in each object in array to SQL.

To do this, I've written a loop to iterate through the array, and insert each property as a new entry into sql.

However, when i try to execute the function after the connect, the function returns error  `Request is not a constructor`

Here is the full code below. Is there some scope issue here, or am I not correctly handling  the tedious js events properly or is there some sort of issue with my for loop?

```
var jsonArray = [];
let jsonobj = {
    test: "1",
    test2: "2"
}

let jsonobj1 = {
    test: "23",
    test2: "54"
}
jsonArray.push(jsonobj)
jsonArray.push(jsonobj1)



jsonArray.push(jsonobj)
    var config = {  
        server: '123',  //update me
        authentication: {
            type: 'default',
            options: {
                userName: '123', //update me
                password: '1234'  //update me
            }
        },

        options: {
            // If you are on Microsoft Azure, you need encryption:
            //encrypt: true,
        requestTimeout: 30 * 1000,
            trustServerCertificate: true,
            database: 'db', //update me
            rowCollectionOnRequestCompletion: true,
            rowCollectionOnDone: true

        }
    };  
    var connection = new Connection(config); 
    connection.on('debug', function(err) { console.log('debug:', err);}) 
    connection.on('connect', function(err) {  
           });



    for (var i = 0; i < jsonArray.length; i++){
        var sql = `insert into store (storekey,ip,port) values ( \'${jsonArray[i].test2}\' , '2' , '6');` 
        executeStatement1(sql)
      }

    var Request = require('tedious').Request;  
    var TYPES = require('tedious').TYPES;  
    function executeStatement1(sql) {  
        request = new Request(sql, function(err) {  
         if (err) {  
            console.log(err);}  
        });    
        
        request.on('row', function(columns) {  
            columns.forEach(function(column) {  
              if (column.value === null) {  
                console.log('NULL');  
              } else {  
                console.log(" success " + column.value);  
              }  
            });  
        });       
        connection.execSql(request);  
    }
```

Comment: First, use let: `let request = new Request(sql....`. Second, at the top of the function call `console.log(typeof Request);` to check if the variable has changed.